# Twilio Call Initiated From a Form on Website

Tags: twilio, twilio-click-to-call

Scenario:

We are a marketing company that connects web leads to our customers using Twilio. I need to know how to make the following scenario happen:

1. Customer on the web Enter their Name and Phone Number and Submits the form
2. I determine which of our customers handles that Zip Code
3. I initiate a call using Twilio between the Web Customer and Our Customer(who we use a Twilio number to forward the lead to them).

What steps do I need to take to make this happen?

Comment: This question is overly broad. Stackoverflow is designed with asking questions regarding specific problems. Not a general A-Z of how to get your project working. You are also missing very important information such as server setup, Database setup, and programming language used. Philnash gave you some great advice to get started with. I would go with that and come back when you have a more specific need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The best thing to do here would be to take a look through the [Twilio click to call tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/click-to-call/php/laravel). (That's a link to the PHP version, but there are more languages available.)

The tutorial can cover everything you need except for looking up your customer that handles the zip code. I'm not sure what your current system looks like, so I can't comment on how you'd do that right now.